# Firestore encodable not including Firestore DocumentID

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im using Firebase Firestore in my project, and I have figured out that I need to use @DocumentId to properly decode firebase "_id" property into my codable struct.

My issue is that I need to save the encoded object (for now I'm using userdefaults) and re-decode the object later on in my apps lifecycle.

When I encode my Firestore object with Firestore.encode, it loses the id property as it becomes encoded to [String: Any] so when I try to decode the fetched pre-encoded object, I'm unable to do so.

For now I am storing the ID property separately, and re-adding it to the object once decoded.

Is this the correct way to handle Firestore codable? Or is there a cleaner way to encode and then decode Firestore encoded objects?

Comment: The only way to property decode DocumentId is with the Firestore tools, there is really no reason to store a Firestore object in UserDefaults

Comment: certainly userdfeaults isn't the best way for this, but I'm just prototyping something out. how about persistent data within the app?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use you can use the swift provided decdoders, why would you need additional local storage?

Comment: a common pattern for mobile development is persistent storage. in my case I'd like to encode objects and store them on the device. file system, memory, and GRDB are all great choices for this task.

Comment: I know about persistent storage, I mean why would you need it with Firestore it provides everything you need. But in any case you can't decode a Firestore wrapper with standard decoding methods, you have to use Firestore

Comment: sure I understand, there must be more to firebase that I haven't learned yet. thanks for the help.

Comment: Saving data to the device is completely justified if you want to cache some data without making needless reads to firebase. Obviously (not storing sensitive user data in userDefaults) I am also having an issue with storing the id (@DocumentID) as the encoder ignores it for not actually being part of the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7242)

> The solution is to explicitly ask for the DocumentID wrapping of
> DocumentReference and then manually unwrap yourself. It looks like
> this:
>
> ```
> ref = try container.decode(DocumentID<DocumentReference>.self, forKey: .ref)
>   .wrappedValue
> ```

Also check these similar cases for more information:

[How can I get the document ID when using Codable in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72106241/how-can-i-get-the-document-id-when-using-codable-in-firestore)

[Getting DocumentID when decoding Firestore struct with custom decodable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67545856/getting-documentid-when-decoding-firestore-struct-with-custom-decodable)

[Getting document ID when decoding firestore document using Swift Codable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67304222/getting-document-id-when-decoding-firestore-document-using-swift-codable)